# Replacing "<" with "*" with a Python regex

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to go through strings in a list "listb", replacing the character "<" with "*".

I tried like this:

```
import re
for i in listb:
    i = re.sub('\<','\*', 0)
```

But I keep getting TypeError: expected string or buffer.

Not sure what am I doing wrong and examples on the net were not much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

As per Seth's comment, the best way to do this using regular expressions is going to be:

```
listb = [re.sub(r'<',r'*', i) for i in listb]
```

As @Paco, said, you should be using [str.replace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.replace#str.replace) instead. But if you still want to use re:

You're putting `0` where the string is supposed to go! The `TypeError` is from the that third parameter. It's an int, needs to be a string.

Side note: always use raw strings, denoted by `r''`, in your regexes, so you don't have to escape.

```
>>> listb = ['abc', '<asd*', '<<>>**']
>>> for i in listb:
...     i = re.sub(r'<',r'*', i)
...     print i
... 
abc
*asd*
**>>**
>>> listb
['abc', '<asd*', '<<>>**']
```

if you want a new list with all those replaced, do:

```
>>> listx = []
>>> for i in listb:
...     listx.append(re.sub(r'<',r'*', i))
... 
>>> listx
['abc', '*asd*', '**>>**']
>>> listb
['abc', '<asd*', '<<>>**']
>>> listb = listx
```

If you really don't want to create a new list, you can iterate through the indices.

Note that you're not changing `i` in the list. I would create a new list here. Each `i` here is its own variable, which doesn't point to listb.

Comment: This could be done in a list comprehension on one line: `listb = [re.sub(r'<',r'*', i) for i in listb]`.  This avoids creating a new list name, and also makes it so you don't have to iterate through the indices.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes, and that's a much better and more pythonic way to do it. I wanted to make it as close as possible to his original code though. I'm going to add your comment to my answer for completeness. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, problem solved. However, I can't believe that EVERY tutorial I took a look says that final argument in re.sub is number of times replacement should be made, with "0" as unlimited. Also, I would logically expect that sub really does substitution, changing the original value. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @user2684432 if you look at the docs that I linked, the final **optional** argument takes the number of times to be replaced. Default is 0. So the code I really gave was `i = re.sub(r'<',r'*', i, 0, 0)` where the 0s were default. Also, thanks for the 1000 rep :)

Comment: `sub()` not doing substitution wouldn't be your problem anyway. The `for` loop syntax is. The `i` creates a new variable each time, not a pointer to the element in the list.

Comment: For example, `>>> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in list:
...     i = 3
... 
>>> list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Could someone also explain why does my original statement i = re.sub('\<','\*', i) for '<3' returns '\\*3' instead of just '*3' ???

Comment: @user2684432 weird escaping things. Just use raw strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> my_string = 'fowiejf<woiefjweF<woeiufjweofj'
>>> my_string.replace('<', '*')
'fowiejf*woiefjweF*woeiufjweofj'
```

Why are you using the re module for such a simple thing? you can use the `.replace` method.